# Rename the podcast to something other than "Blog - Stack Overflow"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, podcast

When scrolling through my list of podcasts on my iPhone, it always catches me off guard that the SO podcast is titled **'Blog - Stack Overflow'**, which is different from *every* single other podcast I listen too, which follow more traditional naming styles.

My I suggest a few?

- **Jeff & Joel's Most Excellent Podcast**
- **Two Bloggers and a Bag-o-'Pinions**
- **ZZZZ Best Podcast**
- **Syntax Error** *(Get it? SO, SF, SU and now SE!)*
- **"Four to Six Weeks": The Geek Drinking Game**

or, if those are a bit too silly, then maybe just...

- **Stack Overflow - Podcast**

I'm sure others have suggestions.  The point is, having the podcast title start with 'Blog' is just wrong.

Comment: Additionally, some podcasts I subscribe to seem to be able to add some textual description of the episode contents in that show up on the iPhone, that would also be nice.

Comment: At least it's not a "The Blog - Stack Overflow" (for those of us without smart ordering on our feed readers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about...

### The Stack Exchange Podcast

Catchy, eh?

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, **Stack Overflow - Podcast** is the way to go

Comment: No green background?

Comment: They removed it. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/help-stackexchange-with-colors/